# Examples of Jónsson Models

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $T$ be a complete first order theory. Suppose that $M\models T$. Then, $M$ is said to be a Jónsson Model of $T$ if for all $N$, such that $N\prec M$ and $N\models T$, we have $|N|<|M|$ (Note that some texts also assume that $M$ must be uncountable).

Note that if we leave out the size condition, then the theory of arithmetic has a Jónsson model of size $\aleph_0$. This model is $(\mathbb{N};0,\leq,+,\times)$, i.e. the standard natural numbers. Note that this model is trivially Jónsson since any proper subset is not a model of arithmetic (which is what happens in the countable case for all theories).

I was curious if anyone had any examples of theories with uncountable Jónsson models and what explicitly those models look like (the only posts I could find were about what theories never have uncountable Jónsson models, e.g. atomless Boolean algebras).

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean "$N$ is a proper elementary substructure of $M$" rather than just a "proper substructure" in your definition of Jónsson models? Anyway, another example of uncountable Jónsson models is provided by Corollary 2.1.13 in the Kossak–Schmerl book (*The Structure of Models of Peano Arithmetic*, Oxford Science Publications, 2006).

Comment: On the one hand, one can view the Kossak–Schmerl example in my previous comment (which was also given by Enayat in the MO post that tetori linked to) as an example of Jónsson models *even* when there is no elementarity condition in the definition: simply Skolemize the language of arithmetic.

Comment: On the other hand, your example $(\mathbb N;0,{\leqslant},{+},{\times})$ does *not* seem to work without the elementarity condition in the definition because $(2\mathbb N;0,{\leqslant},{+},{\times})$ is a proper (though not elementary) substructure of $(\mathbb N;0,{\leqslant},{+},{\times})$.  The situation is of course different when 1 is in the language.